# Classes.jar folder is empty when using latest version of library from jcenter

Tags: android, gradle, bintray, jcenter

I have successfully uploaded the android library through android studio terminal on Bintray and library is also added to JCenter. Now, I used gradle dependency code snippet in gradle file. it has sync successfully for version "1.0.0".

Next, I updated the library version from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1 and upload that library to Bintray. It's successfully uploaded. also, I used gradle dependency code snippet in gradle file. its also completed sync successfully for version 1.0.1 as well.

But I could not access the library class and function. because the class or java file does not exist in classes.jar folder of the external libraries of the project. (clasess.jar folder is empty.)

Help is appreciated!

My .gradle file of module is here,

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

ext {
    bintrayRepo = 'WebViewOverlayvcx'
    bintrayName = 'WebViewOverlayvcx'

    publishedGroupId = 'org.sumitdemo'
    libraryName = 'WebViewOverlayvcx'
    artifact = 'WebViewOverlayVCX'

    libraryDescription = 'A widget to load WebView as an Overlay.'

    siteUrl = 'https://github.com/sumitdemo/mylibDemo'
    gitUrl = 'https://github.com/sumitdemo/mylibDemo.git'

    libraryVersion = '1.0.2'

    developerId = 'sumitdemo'
    developerName = 'sumit Tyagi'
    developerEmail = 'sumit.k@vcloudx.com'

    licenseName = 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
    licenseUrl = 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
    allLicenses = ["Apache-2.0"]
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {

            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

//Add these lines to publish library to bintray
//Place it at the end of the file
//apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/blundell/release-android-library/master/android-release-aar.gradle'
apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuuneoi/JCenter/master/installv1.gradle'
apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuuneoi/JCenter/master/bintrayv1.gradle'
```

And my project's .gradle file is,

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.4'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.4.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url  "http://jcenter.bintray.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Now I am using `"compile 'org.sumitdemo:WebViewOverlayVCX:1.0.2'"` in app's .gradle file.

My Bintray Library project is here,
https://bintray.com/shashank/WebViewOverlayvcx

and you can find out my Github repo here, https://github.com/sumitdemo/mylibDemo

Comment: After uploading library to Bintray, I am using "compile 'org.sumitdemo:demoproject:1.0.0" in gradle file. but by updating the version of library and upload that library to Bintray then I am using "compile 'org.sumitdemo:demoproject:1.0.1". Now i am unable to access classes from library.

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for your comment. I have edited my question. Could you please help me to resolve my issue.

Comment: Hey @cricket_007 I have edited my code and provide .gradle file code. and also provide link of github module repo and Bintray repo.

Comment: @cricket_007 Please help me to resolve the issue

Comment: You have an AAR file. It's not clear how you're importing it because you need `@aar` after the version number.  Or see https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html#AddDependency Also, do you need Bintray? Take examples from most Android libraries that include "sample app" modules, just include the whole source code of the library, if all else fails

Comment: @cricket_007 I am using **"apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuuneoi/JCenter/master/installv1.gradle'**  in module's .gradle file for aar. And yes i need bintray to upload library to use globally.